# join performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm trying to optimise my queries to make the website load faster

```
SELECT ac.id as id, ac.first_name, ac.last_name, ac.email, ac.company_name, upd8r_twitter_accts.id as twitter, upd8r_facebook_accts.id as facebook 
FROM upd8r_user_accts ac  
LEFT OUTER JOIN upd8r_twitter_accts ON ac.id = upd8r_twitter_accts.user_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN upd8r_facebook_accts ON ac.id = upd8r_facebook_accts.user_id 
WHERE ac.`rfid` = '' AND ac.last_name != '' AND ac.`owner_id` = '114' 
ORDER BY ac.`last_name` asc
```

without the joins the query runs in  0.0001 seconds but with the joins it runs 0.3432 seconds..

How do i go about speeding this up?

Comment: You forgot to post "the query without the joins".

Comment: Every questions about queries performance should start with 1) EXPLAIN 2) All dependent tables descriptions.

Comment: Can you have more than one twitter and/or facebook accounts per `user_id`?

Comment: oops.. you have no accounts of either fb or twitter or you may have more than one- the reason for the joins is to show that a user has gone through the auth  process for each of these networks

Comment: @Chris: currently, if a user has 2 twitter accounts and 3 facebook accounts, the query will return 6 records. Is it intended? If not, which account do you expect to return?

Comment: hmmm.. maybe replacing the joins with subqueries would be better?

Comment: @ChrisMccabe: "replacing the joins with subqueries would be better" is a nice answer for "which account do you expect to return"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  ac.id as id, ac.first_name, ac.last_name, ac.email, ac.company_name,
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    upd8r_twitter_accts
        WHERE   upd8r_twitter_accts.user_id = ac.id
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 1
        ) twitter,
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    upd8r_facebook_accts
        WHERE   upd8r_facebook_accts.user_id = ac.id
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 1
        ) facebook
FROM    upd8r_user_accts ac
WHERE   ac.`rfid` = ''
        AND ac.`owner_id` = '114'
        AND ac.last_name > ''
ORDER BY
        ac.`last_name` asc
```

Create the following indexes:

```
upd8r_user_accts (rfid, owner_id, last_name)
upd8r_twitter_accts (user_id, id)
upd8r_facebook_accts (user_id, id)
```